# Exported Blender Model "faces" the wrong way When Importing to SceneKit

Tags: xcode, scenekit, blender

I've bought a 3D model form TurboSquid, and I need to scale it down to an exact size. I'm a complete newbie when it comes to 3D modelling and Blender but I've managed to find enough tutorials to do this and export the file.

The problem is that I can only get it to export a view from the corner of the object, which I problematic as I want to line-up several of the objects together as part of my ARKit app.

I'm exporting as a Collada .dae file, selecting "Selection Only" as I only need the model, no lights or camera (is this right?).

[image: As you can see, I can only get a corner view]

Is there any specific way it needs to point in Blender? Would aligning it with the camera help (even though I'm exporting the object only)? Can I select a side to be the "front"?

I can angle it somewhat correctly in the SceneKit Editor but I'd prefer to do it in Blender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't remember where I got this or I would happily give credit, but it's how I got my Turbo Squid models to work.  I needed to flip mine around and fix the Y-Up axis, but you might be able to fix your rotation with this.

Make sure everything is selected and press R (for rotate). Just like with scaling, you’ll find that mouse movement rotates the selected objects. But we want to do a particular rotation: 180 degrees around Blender’s Z-axis. To do that quickly, assuming you already pressed R, press Z, then type 180, and press Enter. From my experience, doing this rotation will correct the orientation of your model.
Just as with scale, to apply rotation permanently, press Ctrl+A. In the menu that pops up, click “Rotation”.

Set Y-Up for Scenekit if you need it.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/scntool --convert fighter0.dae --format c3d --output out.dae --force-y-up --force-interleaved --look-for-pvrtc-image

Comment: When I rotate mine and export it, it just reverts the rotation. Anyone know why that might happen?

Comment: My issue was that I also had to redo all the animations because the moment they start, the characters goes back to pointing the wrong way.